# Can we send the stream of hardware camera which is connected to android device with the use of Amazon Kinesis Video Streams with WebRTC?

Tags: android, amazon-kinesis

The hardware which is raspberry pi, is connected to an android mobile device via wifi-network. The raspberry has a connected camera. I can fetch the stream from the hardware camera and show it in a Custom SurfaceView in Android Application from the HTTP URL. The format for video capturing is MJPEG.

What I need to achieve is to send the live video stream of that hardware camera to WebRTC kinesis video streams from the android application.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear what your scenario is. If you refer to Kinesis Video Stream then your RPi could stream directly into KVS using the KVS Producer SDK.

If, however, your device needs to act as a WebRTC master then you can use KVS embedded WebRTC project. There is a master sample application that you can model your application after.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We can achieve the streaming from RPi but it requires the internet. In our scenario, we are not able to provide the internet to RPi. So that we need to send the stream to WebRTC from mobile device. So is there any other way for the same?

Comment: One of the ideas is to run an app based on the GStreamer master sample application included in the AWS Kinesis Video Streams Embedded SDK on the RPi and run a hybrid master/viewer application on the Android side. On the internet it acts as a master and as soon as you get an offer you could pass it as a viewer to the RPi. Not sure if I see the whole picture clearly but your RPi might have a local network to the Android right? So it could do P2P with Android device over the local net.

Comment: Yes the RPi device is connected with the local wifi network to the android. How to install and use GStreamer and run embedded SDK sample on android? Can you please guide me?

Comment: There are few paths you can take.1) Build AWS KVS Embedded SDK for Android 2) Build http://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/ and overwrite the frame code.